# Windows 8 partition safe to delete

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm fairly new to Windows since XP.  After Windows XP, I happily moved to Linux.  Now, I'm back and am looking to dual boot a new Windows 8 machine and am a little disoriented on the new partition scheme.   I would post a screenshot of the HDD partition table, but I don't have enough reputation points to do so, so the following is a list (per linux):

```
Partition   FileSys   Label               Size        flags
/dev/sda1   fat32     SYSTEM             100.00MB    boots
/dev/sda2   ntfs      Recovery           900.00MB    hidden, diag
/dev/sda3   unknown  Microsoft reserved  128.0MB     msftres
/dev/sda4   ntfs                         97.69GB
/dev/sda5   ntfs                         450.00MB    hidden,diag
/dev/sda6   ntfs     Restore             20.01GB     hidden,diag
```

I want to delete all non-critical parts and shrink the Win OS partition,  to make room for Linux. I need someone to help me with what I can delete.  I'm not worried about system restore feature of Win8.  And I have already made a Recovery USB as well as an image of the entire HDD in good working order.

I assume the SYSTEM (/dev/sda1) and /dev/sda4 are required. So I'll leave that alone.

I'm pretty sure I can delete /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda6.  So it's going.

I would like to also delete /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda6.  What is the purpose of these partition, can I delete it?

Help, please!

Comment: For proper operation of Windows 8 you need all those partitions. If e.g. you delete the recovery and restore partitions, you cannot make a refresh. The 450MB partition seems to be the tools partition - not sure. But you are right. For basic operation you need only the system partition (if that is the active partition) and the C partition. Ultimately though you should get a bigger disk. If you now install Linux in double boot, Windows will not boot any more unless you fix the Grub.

Comment: @whs Thanks.  I appreciate your help.   I don't need a bigger HDD; in fact, I would be satisfied by simply shrinking the Win8 OS partition and fitting Linux in the void.  Ultimately, though, what I want is simplicity (save for the dual boot) and that means getting MS's fluff out of the way.   I understand the purpose of their recovery/restore functions, but compared to other methods of recovery/refresh, I consider them suboptimal.

Comment: I guess. If you make frequent images, there is no need for all this recovery stuff. But your disk is very small. Maybe you want to consider migrating to a SSD. Yesterday they sold at Newegg 128GB models for $49 and 240GB models are around $80. That would give you a real speed boost.